# Parallel pipeline on a list of nodes

Tags: jenkins

I'm using a loop like this one to start a parallelStageMap:

```
def generateTestStage(job_name, nodes_label) {
    return {
        stage(job_name) {
            node(nodes_label) {
                /* stage stuff */
            }
        }
    }
}

pipeline
for(item in nodesByLabel(label: "myNodes", offline: true)) { // nodesByLabel requires "Pipeline Utility Steps" plugin
    stagesMap[ "${item}" ] = generatePrepareStage("${item}")
}

stagesMap += JOB_MAP.collectEntries() { key, val ->
    [ "$key" : generateTestStage(key, val) ]
}

parallel parallelStageMap
```

The idea is to prepare all available nodes in a label before testing them.
Our job is very long (4 hours on 8 nodes in parallel), and sometimes a node may become offline or in maintenance for some reasons.

In this case, I have 2 scenarios:

- nodesByLabel with offline: false: if a node is offline before job starts, and become online after, generatePrepareStage will not be executed so all later tests maybe not correctly setup
- nodesByLabel with offline: true: job will wait for offline nodes to become online to finish the job, so a job may take far longer than expected (several days maybe if users did not seen it)
  nodesByLabel documentation: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#nodesbylabel-list-of-nodes-by-label-by-default-excludes-offline-nodes

To solve this, I would like to store a list of online nodes instead of node(nodes_label) in generateTestStage, but I haven't find a solution to do this.

Is anyone has an idea to do this solution ? Or maybe should I structure my parallelStageMap differently ?

Comment: The only idea I could recommend - don't do it. This approach will never give you any reliable results because you don't have an ability to reassign the node on-the-fly. Also, since there anyway is a chance that a node goes offline during the build, I don't see any reason to repeat the logic that Jenkins already has - upon the job start, it will use only the online nodes, and it will automatically try to continue the build when the node is available again. Instead, I would recommend to invest in performance improvements AND to figure out why and when your nodes could go offline to avoid that.

Comment: Hi Alexander,
Thanks for your suggestions.
I don't think I need to reassign the node on-the-fly, just to prevent execution on a node that has not been prepared for this campaign. I does not look to be on the fly, but at the start of the test campaign.
I will not develop why, but I cannot invest in performance or preventing a node to go offline.
If you ever know how to use a kind of list of online nodes, please tell me. I will give a try, even if it is a bad solution for us. It might help for future evolutions of our pipeline.